# Can we construct a function $g$ and a partition $\pi$ such that $\pi(g)<v(g)<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let g be a function defined on [a,b], 
and partition $\triangle=\{ a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b\}$
$\delta(\triangle)=\displaystyle\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}(t_{k+1}-t_k)$

and $\pi$ be a partition sequence, that is 
$\pi=\{\triangle_n:\triangle_n\subseteq\triangle_{n+1}, \delta(\triangle_n)\to0\}$.

Let the variation of $g$ over $\triangle$ be $\triangle(g)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(g(t_{k-1})-g(t_k))$

and let $\pi(g)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\triangle_n(g)$
and let $v(g)=\displaystyle\sup_{\triangle}\triangle(g)$.

(a) Can we construct a function g and partition $\pi$ such that $\pi(g)<v(g)<\infty$?

(b) If $g$ is either right or left continuous at each point of [a,b], is $\pi(g)=v(g)$ for any $\pi$?

Comment: I think an absolute value sign is missing in your definition of $\Delta (g)$.

Comment: Any strictly increasing function meets the requirements in a). The answer to b) is  NO.